# jhipster, spring jpa order by and losing null values

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jhipster

I am using JHipster project(spring mvc+angularjs)
I have a table and when one row is null when i want to order this column it loses the null rows.

```
Function.query({requestUrlUserType: $state.current.data.requestUrlUserType, page: $scope.page - 1, size: $scope.itemsPerPage, sort: [$scope.predicate + ',' + ($scope.reverse ? 'asc' : 'desc'), 'id'], },
                function(result, headers) {
```

from the side of server i dont have nothing more than

```
Page<Request> findAllByState(@Param( "id" ) Long stateId, Pageable pageable);
```

i fount  [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Sort.NullHandling.html) but it does't help a lot

Comment: i make some changes like    orderList.add(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.ASC, requestUrlUserTypeName,Sort.NullHandling.NULLS_FIRST));   and       Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(pageNumber, pageSize, new Sort(orderList));    but nothing until now :'(